# What's the metric num_queries in Google suggest

Tags: php, api, seo

I use http://www.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&oe=utf8&hl=fr&q=test and i want to know num_queries for each keywords is the number of query for this per day, month, years ?

Do you know that ?

Answer (score 0):

I verified that it's the total number of results that are returned for the search. You can see for yourself by plotting the autosuggest num_queries against the total number of results that are listed when you search google with that term. You'll find an extremely linear relationship.